# Are Rows and Columns collections?

Tags: excel, vba

Rows and Columns are properties of the object Range. They are also members of the Globals class.

Are they collections? MSDN never refer to this objects as collections, yet they seem to behave the same  way.

Thanks,
Eduardo.

Comment: What about here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174290(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Thanks Roland. I've searched the document you've mentioned and did not found any reference to the Rows or Columns object. This might sugest that Rows and Columns objects are not collections.

In fact, it sugests that their similar behaviour is just for convenience. Would you say so?

Comment: Rows and Columns are properties of Application, Worksheet, and Range objects. They are not collections themselves, but are used to refer to Range objects (all of them return Ranges). Properties relate to objects in a way similar to how names relate to persons - names are not persons, but are used to identify individual persons. Columns(1) refers to all cells with the Column property of 1